# Java android eclipse the type okio.BufferedSource cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The type okio.BufferedSource cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I added to project a jar moshi and when I want to call this :

```
 RootObject test = MyApplication.getDictionaries().fromJson(json);
```

I see this error , I added in build path this jar

Answer (score 0):

I download and added a okio.BufferedSource jar and it works